# Bootstrap Popover with Added Close Option Submits Form Also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in this [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/LRCNm/7/), I have a Boostrap Popover that is able to close with an outside click as well as with a click on the "x."

However, when this popover is placed within a form, it also submits the form.

Is there a way to get the functionality of this closeable popover without submitting the form once clicked?

HTML:

```
<form action="quote-calculator.php" method="post">
    <div class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
      <a href="#" class="more-info btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Click to toggle popover</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
        var isVisible = false;
        var clickedAway = false;

        $('.btn-danger').popover({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual'
            }).click(function(e) {
                $(this).popover('show');
            $('.popover-content').append('<button class="close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 6px;">&times;</button>');
                clickedAway = false
                isVisible = true
                e.preventDefault()
            });

        $(document).click(function(e) {
          if(isVisible & clickedAway)
          {
            $('.btn-danger').popover('hide')
            isVisible = clickedAway = false
          }
          else
          {
            clickedAway = true
          }
        });
```

Comment: Change the button that closes it to an anchor? http://jsfiddle.net/LRCNm/8/

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your button element to an anchor element.

http://jsfiddle.net/LRCNm/8/

```
$('.popover-content').append('<a class="close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 6px;">&times;</a>');
                    clickedAway = false
                    isVisible = true
                    e.preventDefault()
                });
```

Comment: I love simple answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `preventDefault()` here:

```
        $(document).click(function(e) {
          if(isVisible & clickedAway)
          {
            $('.btn-danger').popover('hide')
            isVisible = clickedAway = false
            e.preventDefault()
          }
          else
          {
            clickedAway = true
          }
        });
```

Comment: Is that preferable to changing '<button class="close" to something like '<a class="close"?